# Face book multi friend selector

Tags: facebook, multi-friend-selector

I wan to show the facebook popup to the user from where user select the friends and when he click select then the selected user ids return. I want to do this Flex but if you can tell me how to do it in php it will also very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it in JavaScript:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

More to the bottom of the page there's more info about retrieving the user_ids.